# Error function SQL OrientDB

Tags: sql, orientdb

I have this function in my DB.

[image]

Can look data in V.

[image]

Where is my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried your case and it works if you write the entire command on the same line, as in my example:

[image]

and this is the result:

[image]

Hope it helps

Regards

Comment: OMG... Thank u so much. =)